# Ubuntu won't upgrade

Tags: 16.04

I get this message;

> The upgrade has aborted. The upgrade needs a total of 97.8 M free 
>   space on disk '/boot'. Please free at least an additional 17.5 M of 
>   disk space on '/boot'. Empty your trash and remove temporary packages 
>   of former installations using 'sudo apt-get clean'.

I've tried:

```
sudo apt-get clean
```

and

```
sudo apt-get autoclean
```

But none of them worked.

Answer (score 3):

Your `/boot` partition is full , you need to free some space.
I guess you have many old kernels installed so you may want to remove them.
Open terminal and type `uname -r` this is the newest kernel **don't remove it**.

Then type `dpkg --list | grep linux-image` this will output the list of installed kernels , you can remove any/all kernels from the list except the one you got with `uname -r` by typing `sudo apt-get purge linux-image-x.x.x.x-generic`.

Comment: It's the first time Ubuntu has been installed on the laptop but I'll try it anyways.